# How to decrement nullable int by1 in mvc4 c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one action method as below:

```
public PartialViewResult batchSave(int? clientId, string uploadidList, int? currentFilter, int? page)
{
    if(page!=null)
    {
        page--;// This is also not working
        page=page-1; //Does not works
    } 
}
```

I tried as above but it does not decrement. Basically it is nullable; so is there any method to solve this? Thank you

Comment: Yes for example if the page is 3 then i want to decrement by 1 so page is 2 now.

Comment: What do you mean "does not works"? The value doesn't change in the debugger when you add a breakpoint, or the same page is displayed regardless, or ..?

Comment: Sorry, mistunderstood - see musefan answer, but what do you want to do if its `null`?

Comment: i dont want to decrement if it is null so i will check for null before decrementing

Comment: Simple decrement `page--` works. I guess, the problem is in passing `page` back from this method.

Comment: Sorry, for my premature answer. I tested your original code and it actually works fine. Nullables obviously have support for it. What are you trying to do with `page` afterwards? Why do you think it isn't working?

Comment: There must be some issue while passing the data to the mehtod. Code works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple decrement with `--` works fine.

```
int? t = 50;
t--; // t now == 49
```

I guess, the problem is in comparing result after this method:

```
public void Dec(int? t) 
{
    if (t != null) 
    {
        t--; //if initial t == 50, then after this t == 49.
    }
}
...
int? t = 50;
Dec(t); // but here t is still == 50
```

Take a look at @PaulF answer, it contains explanation, why copy of `int?` is passing to method, instead of reference.

As you can not mark arguments for ASP.NET MVC4 controller method with `ref` or `out` keyword (it will cause an `ArgumentException` while calling to method), I recommend you to use a single class with multiple properties.

So, while decrementing, you will have a deal with a property of class, which is passing by reference, and not with a copy of `int?` variable (AFAIK it is a good practice).

In your case your code can be modified as following:

```
public class PassItem 
{
   public int? clientId { get; set; }
   public string uploadidList { get; set; }
   public int? currentFilter { get; set; }
   public int? page { get; set; }
}

public PartialViewResult batchSave(PassItem passItem)
{
    if(passItem.page != null)
    {
        passItem.page--;
    } 
}
```

In this case you will work with an object, not with a multiple copies of object.

If you are calling with method from View, `ASP.NET` default binder will automatically create an instance of `PassItem` and set it's properties with required values.

Comment: @PaulF Yes, you are right about passing parameters with `ref` or `out` keyword. It will be fine for regular methods, but asp net 4 controller method with `ref` parameter will cause `ArgumentException`.

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole AFAIK passing multiple params to controller method is a bad practice, instead of passing a single object, which contains a set of required parameters

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov your comments make a good point if they were included in the answer itself it would improve the clarity and quality of your answer

Comment: Thank you. So i need to create one array object and send parameters to controller method right if i am not wrong?

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole if you will create a class with properties with same names as your input parameters and put it in the method arguments instead of your arguments - `.NET` default binder will automatically create an object of class on your request.

Comment: Thank you for the model. i am sending values to action method through ajax. for example    data: {  'clientId': clientId,'uploadidList': uploadidList,'page':pers},
                url: '/documentVerification/batchSave',

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole you have no need to modify your ajax request method. ASP.NET binder will successfully parse it into input model.

Comment: i want to try this. I want to improve my coding standards. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Nullable types are treated as structs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) - so are passed by value as parameters. You are decrementing the value on the stack, if you want to change the actual value you need to pass page as a ref or out parameter

```
public PartialViewResult batchSave(int? clientId, string uploadidList, int? currentFilter, ref int? page)
```

{
    }

Answer (score 0):

You decrease a copy of the struct passed by value. Use the 'ref'

```
static void foo(ref int? val)
{
    if (val != null)
    {
        --val;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int? val = 5;
    foo(ref val);
}
```

It is also better to use a pre-operation, as post-operation returns a copy of the value, which was before the operation. This, in general, not optimal. Pre-operation does not use copies.

Comment: Why are you using the pre-operation decrementer when there is no operation other than the decrement?

Comment: @MikeT, post-operation returns a copy of the value, which was before the operation. This, in general, not optimal. Pre-operation does not use copies.

Comment: interesting i wasn't aware of that, that would be useful to include in the answer, preferably with evidential link